# How find this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

solve this equation
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+x}}=x$$

My try: since
$$\sqrt{3}-x^2=\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+x}$$
then
$$(x^2-\sqrt{3})^2=x+\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: The [tag:differential-equations] is inappropriate. Please read a tags' description before applying it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $y = \sqrt{\sqrt3 + x}$, then the equation becomes: $\sqrt3 - y = x^2$, and $y^2 = \sqrt3 + x$.
So: 
$$\begin{align*}
y^2 - x  & = y + x^2 \\
\Rightarrow (y + x)(y - x - 1) & = 0
\end{align*}$$
And we can go from here.

Comment: Please use MathJax for mathematical expressions. For a quick tutorial, see the site FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Square again, you'll get $x=0$ as a possible solution. Remembering that $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ you should be able to factor the equation and get $x=-1$ as a possible solution.  Now solve the remaining quadratic.